# Framing long walls - Lots of 8' sections or should I use longer top plates

Tags: walls, framing

For interior walls (bearing and non) I'm wondering what the preferred method for framing might be on long walls. For example a hallway. Should I just use normal ~8' long 2x4 as top plates and stagger the top and bottom plates a few feet or is it better to buy longer top plate 2x4's to reduce the amount of joints.

Comment: is this new construction or a rehab? Completely different ways of framing these. How long are the longest walls?

Comment: @shirlockhomes rehab, about 23'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continuous top and bottom plate are preferred, and longer 2x4 or 2x6's are available for this. If you need to breakup the wall, then make two separate walls and nail them together, to the floor, and with a staggered top plate. When possible, you want to end the wall near a corner to give the joint more support. Also try to stagger top plates near corners for additional strength.

Answer (score 2):

At 23 feet, there is no way to build it with a continuous sill or plate.  i would also assume in that 23 foot span there may be a few doors? The first step would be to lay a sill plate on the floor on a chalk line and secure it with framing nails or screws. Now you can lay out where your doors are going to live. If you really want to build the walls on the floor and raise them into place, calculate the length between 8 and maybe 12 feet, so all doors are in the span not at an edge. Lay out your walls, be sure to compensate on your height for the sill already laid down. Now when you pick up your wall section it will be shorter than the ceiling height and you will be able to raise it to a full vertical position which you could not do without the shorter dimension. Now set the wall up 1 1/2 inch onto the sill plate already in place, plumb and attach to floor plate and ceiling or strapping. 
Compensate for your 16 o/c where wall sections join so your rock will fit well. Simply nail or screw one segment to the next, checking plumb as you go.